# Generate classes from grammar rules, objects on parse

Tags: objective-c, parsing, parsekit, pegkit

Is it possible to generate .m and .h's for any grammar/ rules so that during parsing it creates an object that represents that rule.

So some grammar

```
coolObjName = Word;
```

could generate a class that is named coolObjName (or some variation) and has a field for the word, and generates the action:

```
coolObjName = Word{
    CoolObjName* newName = [[CoolObjName alloc] initWithWord:POP_STR()];
    PUSH(newName);
};
```

Then a higher level rule such as:

```
myhigherlevel = coolObjName Number;
```

would create a myHigherLevel class that has a coolObjName member and a number, which then adds the action:

```
myhigherlevel = coolObjName Number{
   double num = POP_DOUBLE();
   coolObjName* name = POP(); 
   MyHigherLevel* higherLevel = [[MyHigherLevel alloc] init];
   higherLevel.number = num;
   higherLevel.name = name;
   PUSH(higherLevel);
};
```

Empty tags turn to empty objects and `*` and `+` result in arrays.

Is there a tool that can do this or where would I go to create such. (seems super useful and awesome)

Comment: you want DSL to generate ObjC code?

Answer (score 0):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

There's nothing currently in PEGKit which will inspect your rules and auto-generate ObjC AST or model classes which might match your intent. For now, PEGKit can only produce source code for your **parser**, but not your related AST or model classes.

It is probably very likely that you will be building an **Abstract Syntax Tree** (or Intermediate Representation) in your Actions or Parser Delegate Callbacks. ANLTR has some wonderful high-level **Tree Rewriting** features which allow you to specify in the grammar how to build your AST. Although looking at [the docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~admin/2012/12/08/Tree+rewriting+in+ANTLR+v4) it seems this might have changed significantly since ANTLR 3? Not sure. It used to look like something like this (maybe it still does, I'm not an ANTLR expert):

```
addExpr : lhs=NUM op='+' rhs=NUM -> ^(op lhs rhs);
```

The `->` means *rewrite to tree like…*

And the `^(op …)` means *tree rooted by a plus operator containing children…*.

I would love to add tree rewriting features like this to PEGKit, for the express purpose of building ASTs (but not other model objects). But honestly, it's a huge task, and it is not likely to appear soon.